# Text-alignment with multine list in Bootstrap with glyphicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

Probably a very silly question and most probably very easy to answer for someone else, but I cannot get this to work. Unless I really start goofing around in the CSS.

I am using Bootstrap (last version) which is also using glyphicons as well in several unordered lists. So far it was working perfectly, however when a single line becomes a multiline the text goes under the glyphicon.

Here is a screenshot of what's happening:

[image: glyphicon text alignment]

As you can see in the screenshot the text-lines are aligned under the glyphicon, instead of under the first word (in this case; Lorem).

My HTML is:

```
<ul class="example">
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok aanbiedingglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS for this part is:

```
.example{margin-bottom:0;}
.example li{list-style-type:none;margin:0 0 0 10px;padding:0 0 10px 0;line-height:normal;}
.aanbiedingglyph{color:#d2151a;font-size:1.250em;padding-right:10px;}
```

I tried a few things myself, but I had to change a lot off CSS and had to add several margin-related stuff, which I doubt is a clean way to do it. Is there a better way? Maybe by using ':before'? I never used that, so any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Maybe there is even a way to use Bootstrap default CSS for this?

Comment: Can you share it in fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you arent setting the list item indicator to use the glyphicon (e.g. by setting the content property of `li:before` to the unicode), you will need to add the e.g. below to align the items/icons correctly:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11847/)

```
.example{
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:25px; // give the list items an offset
}
.example .glyphicon{
    width:20px;
    margin-left:-25px; // counteract the offset for the list item icon   
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a media object instead. Like this:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe you have some good reason to use a ul-tag, but if not my above example works fine. No extra CSS needed.

Read more here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media